# What is the speed of a satellite?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, orbital-motion, time-dilation, satellites

Linear velocity $v$ is by definition the runned space $ds$ per time $dt$ elapsed: $v=ds/dt$. If the time elapsed in a specific point on the earth's surface is $t$, the dilated time elapsed on satellite is $t'$. What is the satellite's tangential speed? Is it $ds/dt$ or $ds/dt'$?

Comment: We use Earth time in that calculation, but there are a few options. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Time & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocentric_Coordinate_Time & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeris_time For more background info, see [A Brief History of Time Scales](https://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/timescales.html) by Lick Observatory astronomer Steve Allen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed is a relative quantity. That means that its value depends on the coordinate system chosen. Roughly speaking, if you choose the coordinate system $(t,x,y,z)$ then the speed will be $ds/dt$. If you choose the coordinate system $(t’,x,y,z)$ then the speed will be  $ds/dt’$. Either choice is valid.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend mixing primed and unprimed coordinates... if t' is elapsed time as measured by the satellite (its proper time) then presumably ds'/dt' will be 0 (it is at rest in its own frame), whereas ds/dt is its speed in the Earth-stationary frame of reference. I don't know what physical significance ds/dt' would have, it doesn't seem to me to be a useful quantity (but perhaps I've missed something?)

Comment: @EricSmith such quantities are used all of the time. The TAI is referred to a clock at sea level. The GPS satellites are running a different time, which must be adjusted to match clocks at sea level, effectively mixing $t$ and $t'$. And the standard Schwarzschild coordinates are referenced to a far away observer, which would be yet another time coordinate. Such transformations of coordinates are commonplace.

Comment: Only relative velocity is physically meaningful. We can choose to interpret either satellite or earth to be at rest.And the relative velocity is one,having one value (magnitube=speed).What is the value?

Comment: @elias2010 actually in general relativity there is no one unique value for the relative velocity of two spatially separated objects. Only the relative velocity of objects just passing each other has one unique value

Comment: @Dale Τhe principle of relativity, is that there is no such thing as "earth motion" or "satellite motion", only relative motion.The satellite movement is equivalent of the earth's.Relative velocity is ds/dt = ds/dt' => dt=dt' => no time dilation

Comment: @elias2010 your rough description of the principle of relativity is only valid for special relativity. For situations with gravity you have to generalize it to general relativity. In the resulting curved spacetime it is as I described. There is no unique value for the relative velocity of spatially separated objects.